# MySQL view will not drop in Laravel 5.5 migration

Tags: laravel, mariadb, laravel-5.5

I am trying to write a PHPUnit test case in Laravel 5.5. I'd like to run migrations as part of that process. My users migration script actually creates a view, not a table. And it seems that all other normal tables get created and dropped just as expected. But the users view does not. Any ideas why? I can manually run the DROP statement just fine in PHPMyAdmin. Here is my migration script:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    DB::statement("
    CREATE VIEW users AS
    (
      SELECT
        PD.ID AS id,
        PCI.Username AS username,
        PCI.Username AS first_name
      FROM table1.Person PD
      LEFT JOIN table2.Contact PCI ON PCI.ID = PD.ID
    )
");

}

  public function down()
  {
    DB::statement("DROP VIEW users");
  }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, which DBMS are you using for testing?

Comment: @ChrisForrence i'm using MariaDB

Comment: This might be a Laravel bug, actually. Assuming you're using the RefreshDatabase trait in your test, that trait that drops all tables (and only tables) instead of running the rollback scripts.

Comment: It is: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21193. I think your best bet may be to extend from RefreshDatabase to also drop all views.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is an open issue in the [Laravel github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21193). The proposed workaround which worked for me is to replace the CREATE VIEW in my migration file with CREATE OR REPLACE. So the full up() function will be:

```
public function up()
{
DB::statement("
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users AS
(
  SELECT
    PD.ID AS id,
    PCI.Username AS username,
    PCI.Username AS first_name
  FROM table1.Person PD
  LEFT JOIN table2.Contact PCI ON PCI.ID = PD.ID
)
");

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm surprised no one else has asked about this problem in particular. Maybe the majority of Laravel devs down write down migrations...